# Assign double constant to float variable without warning in C?

Tags: c, floating-point

In C programming language, the floating point constant is double type by default
so `3.1415` is double type, unless use 'f' or 'F' suffix to indicate float type.

I assume `const float pi = 3.1415` will cause a warning, but actually not.

when I try these under gcc with -Wall:

```
float f = 3.1415926;  
double d = 3.1415926;  
printf("f: %f\n", f);  
printf("d: %f\n", d);  
f = 3.1415926f;  
printf("f: %f\n", f);  
int i = 3.1415926;  
printf("i: %d\n", i);
```

the result is:

```
f: 3.141593  
d: 3.141593  
f: 3.141593  
i: 3
```

the result (including double variable) obviously lose precision, but compile without any warning.
so what did the compiler do with this? or did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-Wall` does not enable warnings about loss of precision, truncation of values, etc. because these warnings are annoying noise and "fixing" them requires cluttering correct code with heaps of ugly casts. If you want warnings of this nature you need to enable them explicitly.

Also, your use of `printf` has nothing to do with the precision of the actual variables, just the precision `printf` is printing at, which defaults to 6 places after the decimal point.

Comment: The variadic nature of `printf` ensures the floats are implicitly cast to doubles when passed?

Comment: Yes, although that's rather unrelated to OP's question.

Comment: I wonder which is greater: the number of mistakes which "possible loss of precision from double to float" messages catch, or the number of mistakes that result when code a programmer who has to explicitly forces lots of things to `float` to make the compiler happy, also forces to `float` something which shouldn't have been [e.g. `const float oneTenth = 1.0f/10.0f; float value1 = 8.0f * oneTenth; double value2 = 4.0f * oneTenth;`  Note that if `oneTenth` could have been `double`, everything would have worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

`%f` can be used with `float` and `double`. If you want more precision use

```
printf("f: %.16f",d);
```

And this is what's going on under the hood:

```
float f = 3.1415926;  // The double 3.1415926 is truncated to float
double d = 3.1415926;  
printf("f: %f\n", f);  
printf("d: %f\n", d);  
f = 3.1415926f;       // Float is specified
printf("f: %f\n", f);  
int i = 3.1415926;    // Truncation from double to int
printf("i: %d\n", i);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `%lf` for a double?

Comment: @sharth: `lf` and `f` are different for `scanf` but the same in `printf`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get warnings for this, I believe that `-Wconversion` flags them in mainline gcc-4.3 and later.

If you happen to use OS X, `-Wshorten-64-to-32` has been flagging them in Apple's GCC since gcc-4.0.1.  I believe that clang matches the mainline gcc behavior, however.